# Bootstrap 4 Limit button size, Change space between divs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, bootstrap-4

Firts of all i dont want to change responsive desing. I have 3 questons and thank you for your helps.

1. I need 2 lines in the button. 1st line text is "XXX Pump" and 2nd line is "P01" and the lines shouldnt mix.
2. When i give a very long text button is going bigger then normal size (see 5th button)
3. The space between the buttons are so much. I created a div for each button for responsive design. But i couldnt give less space.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">

    <title>S7-1200 WEB SERVER</title>
  </head>
  <body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
 <div class="container">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
       <li class="nav-item active">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Manual Control <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
</nav>




<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="hero-button text-center">
           <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-danger">
               <span style="font-size:smaller;">Pre Heating Pump</span>
               PU01
           </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="hero-button text-center">
           <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-danger">
               <span style="font-size:smaller;">Pre Heating Pump</span>
               PU01
           </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="hero-button text-center">
           <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-danger">
               <span style="font-size:smaller;">Pre Heating Pump</span>
               PU01
           </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="hero-button text-center">
           <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-danger">
               <span style="font-size:smaller;">Pre Heating Pump</span>
               PU01
           </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="hero-button text-center">
           <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-danger">
               <span style="font-size:smaller;">Pre Heassssssssssssssting Pump</span>
               PU01
           </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="hero-button text-center">
           <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-danger">
               <span style="font-size:smaller;">Pre Heating Pump</span>
               PU01
           </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  
  </div>
</div>



    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1st question you can use `.d-block` class from [display utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/) as an alternative to `<br>` line break.

Example:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary">
  <span class="d-block">Pre Heating Pump</span>
  <span class="d-block">PU01</span>
</a>
```